# Parse small string for name and email?

Tags: python, email

I have a string:

`John Smith <jsmith@gmail.com>`

I would like to get two variables:

name (John Smith) and email (jsmith@gmail.com)

How might I do that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: is the format ALWAYS in that same structure?

Comment: ...and why is this tagged with [RegEx]? `split()` and `strip()` are all you need!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are more forms of valid Internet Email address than you probably realize.  I would suggest using somebody else's code to parse them, like [email.utils.parseaddr](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html).

For example, the following is a valid address:

```
"Rocky J. Squirrel" <rocky.squirrel@gmail.com>
```

Here, the name is `Rocky J. Squirrel`, not `"Rocky J. Squirrel"`.

The following is also legal syntax and shows up regularly in mail headers (note lack of <> delimiters):

```
rocky.squirrel@gmail.com (Rocky J. Squirrel)
```

Although the part in parens is technically just a "comment", most mail clients interpret it as the user's name.  (And so does Python's email.utils.parseaddr.)

To actually do the parsing (saving you reading the docs):

```
>>> import email.utils
>>> email.utils.parseaddr("John Smith <jsmith@gmail.com>")
('John Smith', 'jsmith@gmail.com')
```