# How to extract all names from a block of text

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to scrape names from a chunk of text (from an email body actually) that normally looks similar to this:

```
From: aaa@aaa.com
CC: John Smith <aaa@aaa.com>, Charles <aaa@aaa.com>, Mary Lamb <aaa@aaa.com>, Chino <aaa@aaa.com>, Claudia <aaa@aaa.com>, <aaa@aaa.com>, <bbb@bbb.com>, John <aaa@aaa.com>
Hi there AAA! Hope you had a wonderful time
Best,
AAA
```

I would like to end up with a list variable that holds only the names (first and last if available) of everyone on the CC, discarding the rest of the information. What would be a simple and clean approach using regex? (this is not a test, it's a real app I'm working on and am stuck...). I already was able to extract all emails using a re.findall() with an email matching pattern I found.

Thanks

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209910/parse-small-string-for-name-and-email).

Comment: Dave, while its not exactly what I needed, that question did point me to some new things I am looking into right now. Thanks

Comment: @AvinashRaj true, but that's not really relevant since what I needed was to extract the name part regardless of what the name is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
[:,] ([\w ]+) \<
```

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dN3kB4/1)

---

```
>>> p = re.compile(ur'[:,] ([\w ]+) \<') 
>>> m = re.findall(p, text)
>>> print m
['John Smith', 'Charles', 'Mary Lamb', 'Chino', 'Claudia', 'John']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """From: aaa@aaa.com
... CC: John Smith <aaa@aaa.com>, Charles <aaa@aaa.com>, Mary Lamb <aaa@aaa.com>, Chino <aaa@aaa.com>, Claudia <aaa@aaa.com>, <aaa@aaa.com>, <bbb@bbb.com>, John <aaa@aaa.com>
... Hi there AAA! Hope you had a wonderful time
... Best,
... AAA"""
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=[:,]\s)[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)?(?=\s<)', s)
['John Smith', 'Charles', 'Mary Lamb', 'Chino', 'Claudia', 'John']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex:

```
re.findall("(?:CC: |, )([\w ]*) <\S*@\S*>", str)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will capture strictly what you need.

```
[:,]\s((?:(?![:,<]).)*)\s\<
```

use group 1 to get the text.