# Capture accented characters by modifying a specific regex I have in python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I [asked a question before](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26569328/edit) about extracting matching groups of names & emails from a long email body text into tuples using a regex. Solution worked beautifully extracting names and emails for example from this text:

```
> Begin forwarded message:
> Date: December 20, 2013 at 11:32:39 AM GMT-3
> Subject: My dummy subject
> From: Charlie Brown <aaa@aa-aaa.com>
> To: maria.brown@aaa.com, George Washington <george@washington.com>, =
thomas.jefferson@aaa.com, thomas.alva.edison@aaa.com, Juan =
<juan@aaa.com>, Alan <alan@aaa.com>, Alec <alec@aaa.com>, =
Alejandro <aaa@aaa.com>, Alex <aaa@planeas.com>, Andrea =
<andrea.mery@thomsen.cl>, Andrea <andrea.22@aaa.com>, Andres =
<andres@aaa.com>, Andres <avaldivieso@aaa.com>
> Hi,
> Please reply ASAP with your RSVP
> Bye
```

And using this Regex:

```py
 [:,]\s*=?\s*(?:([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)?))?\s*=?\s*.*?([\w.]+@[\w.-]+)
```

Producing this output:

```py
 [(Charlie Brown', 'aaa@aaa.com'),('','maria.brown@aaa.com'),('George Washington', 'george@washington.com'),('','thomas.jefferson@aaa.com'),('','thomas.alva.edison@aaa.com'),('Juan','juan@aaa.com',('Alan', 'alan@aaa.com'), ('Alec', 'alec@aaa.com'),('Alejandro','aaa@aaa.com'),('Alex', 'aaa@aaa.com'),('Andrea','andrea.mery@thomsen.cl'),('Andrea','andrea.22@aaa.com',('Andres','andres@aaa.com'),('Andres','avaldivieso@aaa.com')]
```

But, I stumbled upon instances where the names on the texts I passed to the regex have special accented characters. How can I update the regex above to not break and also capture names that include accented characters like:

```
 "á", "é", "í", "ó", "ú", "ç", "ö", "ü", "ñ", "à", "è", "ì", "ò", "ù"
```

(and their UPPER counterparts)

Thanks!

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7207366/3297613) would help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `regex` module instead of `re` to support unicode regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207366/3297613). I just changed `[a-z]+` to `\p{L}+` (*which matches any kind of letter from any language*) in the pattern which capture the names.

```
>>> s = """> Begin forwarded message:
> Date: December 20, 2013 at 11:32:39 AM GMT-3
> Subject: My dummy subject
> From: Chrálié Brown <aaa@aa-aaa.com>
> To: maria.brown@aaa.com, George Washington <george@washington.com>, =
thomas.jefferson@aaa.com, thomas.alva.edison@aaa.com, Juan =
<juan@aaa.com>, Alan <alan@aaa.com>, Alec <alec@aaa.com>, =
Alejandro <aaa@aaa.com>, Alex <aaa@planeas.com>, Andrea =
<andrea.mery@thomsen.cl>, Andrea <andrea.22@aaa.com>, Andres =
<andres@aaa.com>, Andres <avaldivieso@aaa.com>
> Hi,
> Please reply ASAP with your RSVP
> Bye"""
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall(r'[:,]\s*=?\s*(?:([A-Z]\p{L}+(?:\s[A-Z]\p{L}+)?))?\s*=?\s*.*?([\w.]+@[\w.-]+)', s)
[('Chrálié Brown', 'aaa@aa-aaa.com'), ('', 'maria.brown@aaa.com'), ('George Washington', 'george@washington.com'), ('', 'thomas.jefferson@aaa.com'), ('', 'thomas.alva.edison@aaa.com'), ('Juan', 'juan@aaa.com'), ('Alan', 'alan@aaa.com'), ('Alec', 'alec@aaa.com'), ('Alejandro', 'aaa@aaa.com'), ('Alex', 'aaa@planeas.com'), ('Andrea', 'andrea.mery@thomsen.cl'), ('Andrea', 'andrea.22@aaa.com'), ('Andres', 'andres@aaa.com'), ('Andres', 'avaldivieso@aaa.com')]
```

Comment: I had a headache of a time installing regex module, but once I passed that hurdle, it did work, thanks.